# Setting boot disk size for goole compute engine

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, gcloud

I'm setting up a GCE instance for machine learning training.  I first did this:

> gcloud compute instances create my_instance --image=pytorch-latest-gpu-v20240128-ubuntu-2004 --image-project=deeplearning-platform-release --accelerator="type=nvidia-tesla-v100,count=1" --custom-extensions --custom-cpu 1 --custom-memory 20GB --boot-disk-size 50GB (some arguments intentionally omitted here)

This command gives a first warning:

> WARNING: You have selected a disk size of under [200GB]. This may result in poor I/O performance. For more information, see: https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/disks#performance.

If I modify the above `gcloud` command to have `--boot-disk-size 200GB`, then I get a second warning:

> - Disk size: '200 GB' is larger than image size: '50 GB'. You might need to resize the root repartition manually if the operating system does not support automatic resizing. See https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/add-persistent-disk#resize_pd for details.

The link in the first warning is not very helpful.  Do I need to be concerned about poor I/O performance warning if I am doing just machine learning model training?  I don't want to slow down the model training since the machines are expensive.

Answer (score 1):

You can ignore the second warning for Ubuntu (and Debian) because automatic resizing of the boot disk is built-in to the Google tools installed with Debian/Ubuntu operating systems.

I wrote an [article](https://www.jhanley.com/blog/google-cloud-debian-9-resize-root-file-system/) that shows how the Google tools perform the resize.